# How to use plugin DataTables with C# .net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables-1.10

I tried to add a table by using `dataTables` jquery plugin in a project `C#` net mvc 5: When I try to call jquery.dataTables.js  and jquery.dataTables.css to the head of the code notthing happen. 
So, I followed a tutorial  , and I add the two files to bundleConfig.cs file, but, no style file has been loaded (the  table is displyed but no style has been applied, also I lost menu style ) .

This is my code:

```
     public class BundleConfig
     {

         public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
          {
                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));


                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

                bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                 // "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
                 "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"
                  ));

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                   "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                 "~/Content/site.css"
                // "~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
                //"~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
                   ));
                BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
                 //bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
                //bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
             }
```

My View (I tried just an example of the net) :

```
     <div style="margin-top:140px;">
       <table class=" distable table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example">
         <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>
                Internet
                Explorer 4.0
            </td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">125.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
         </tr>
        <tfoot>
         <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
          </tr>
       </tfoot>
      </table>
     </div>

    @section scripts
       {
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
               alert("debut");
               $('#example').dataTable();

              alert("finnnn");
           });</script>
      }
```

In _Layout file:

```
     @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: You need to show you view (and how you have added the scripts and css files)

Comment: Please add your view here, so we can help you in a proper way

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Smit,  I added my partial view when I declare the table

Comment: If that is a partial view, then it will not work. You need to put the `@section scripts { ...... }` in the main view

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I must remove @ section { ? If not , please, how I can define my table in a partial view?

Comment: You cannot use sections in partials and scripts should not be in partials anyway. You can keep the partial for the table, but just move the script to the main view

Comment: @StephenMuecke, my problem is that no style is applied, but the table is displayed (table+ sort and search fonctionnalilty.....)

Answer (score 0):

What i am doing to get the same as your question, Just add this to the `.cshtml(View)` file,

**Header link of Datatables .Css and .Js**

```
<link href="~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblOffers" class="table table-hover table-bordered  topBorder row-border stripe" style="width:100%">
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblOffers").DataTable({
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "scrollY": "400px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
        });
        $("#tblOffers_filter input").attr('placeholder', 'Search here');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually render your scripts in your view for this to work

Like so:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```